# the auto urldecode in apache mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

this is my apache `.htaccess` setting with a search page redirect

`(RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /index.php?c=index&m=search&keywords=$1 [L,QSA]),`

if I set the search query in url without `%`, it works [success request without '%'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps9Bf.png) but if a `%` char added to the string, apache with return a [bad request with %](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS9Oq.png) , howerver instead of adding `%` but `%25`, the urlencoded string of `%`, success request when pre encode `%` to `%25`

I want to know about the reason of this situation. I guess in the `RewriteRule` of `.htaccess` an urldecode function worked from Pattern to Substitution, that's why `%` char cannot be recognized by the server, but `%25` can. How can I disable this urldecode function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Because the percent ("%") character serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as "%25" for that octet to be used as data within a URI (RFC 3986)
- I think it's because Apache follows the standards, mod_rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them.. (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)

Easy workaround for "disable" auto url decoding is to use Server-Variables like `REQUEST_URI` or `THE_REQUEST` in RewriteCond Directive (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /search/(.*)
RewriteRule . test.php?c=index&m=search&keywords=%1 [L,QSA]
```

If you use REQUEST_URI, in PHP you must use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Do not use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] or $_GET, otherwise you will get the decoded url.
If you want all $_SERVER doing what you need, use THE_REQUEST instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/search/([^\s]*)
RewriteRule . test.php?c=index&m=search&keywords=%1 [L,QSA]
```

And we just need to put . (dot) in RewriteRule pattern and use %1 instead of $1

Comment: although mentioned in documentation, this solution did not work for me. But B flag works:

`RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /index.php?c=index&m=search&keywords=$1 [L,QSA,B]`