# Using Apache rewrite module when URL contains % characters is adding '52' to each %

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to modify the path of a long URL which includes % characters in it, for example:

```
https://www.my-geoserver.co.uk/geoserver/HNT_Demo/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=HNT_Demo%3ANO2_Wed_h18_WGS&TILED=true&login=admin&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=-132083.18487678468%2C6780270.1570082735%2C-127191.2150665334%2C6785162.126818525
```

When i attempt to use Apache rewrite module, I notice that the % characters are causing problems, so for example the section here:

```
image%2Fpng
```

Upon rewrite becomes (notice 52 has appeared):

```
image%252Fpng
```

`%2F` is the URL Encoded value of a forward slash, so I can't believe this is an uncommon problem.

The code I'm using (for experimental purposes) is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)login=[^&]*(?:&(.*)|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Which should simply remove the login variable which it does.  But I also get a modification of the % values throughout the URL, where in all cases `52` is appearing which I don't think is related to the RewriteRule per say.

Is there a way to allow RewriteRule to work with % values in the URL?  I have tried the following flags (somewhat desperately):

- NC
- NE
- QSA

But with no luck.

**Additional:**

I've just found this very old bug report which shows the same behavior of % being 'escaped' to %25.  Is this possibly a bug?

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39746

This bug is referring to using a reverse proxy and the error being in mod_proxy, well I'm using a reverse proxy to host Tomcat, could this be related?

**Additional 2:**

The answer to a question here:

[the auto urldecode in apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737618/the-auto-urldecode-in-apache-mod-rewrite/43176073#43176073)

Suggests using server variables to get around the % issue, unfortunately, I already am using them.  I tried replacing QUERY_STRING with REQUEST_URI and THE_REQUEST, both of which result in the same behaviour:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)login=[^&]*(?:&(.*)|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Actually, 52 has not appeared but `%` get encoded to `%25`

Comment: Ok thanks!  So how do I stop % getting encoded is the question

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/43176073/2669814

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]` should work fine.

Comment: Yep, but I think its because QUERY_STRING is carrying the %'s which is where the problem might be, I think the RewriteRule might be fine.

Comment: @anubhava - it doesn't though, that's the problem.  It replaces %'s with %25 each time.

Comment: With my suggestion I am getting `image%2Fpng` after redirection.

Comment: Did you apply the RewriteCond statement above it?  The problem lies there.

Comment: Of course, how else I would have got `%1` and `%2` populated?